# R: aggregate a dataframe by setting the maximum number of missing observations per column

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table, aggregate

I need to aggregate a dataframe by a column (group) using the mean value. I would like to aggregate each column only if there are less than (let's say 20%) missing observations for each group in every column (and if not, return NA). Any idea how would I accomplish that? (I can use packages like data.table or dplyr as well)

```
#Sample data
set.seed(123)
dat <- data.frame(group = sample(letters[1:4], 100, replace = T), 
                  x = sample(c(rnorm(4, 12, 0.3), NA), 100, replace = T), 
                  y = sample(c(rnorm(4, 12, 0.3), NA), 100, replace = T), 
                  z = sample(c(rnorm(4, 12, 0.3), NA), 100, replace = T))

head(dat)
```

Comment: There are many ways to *aggregate*. What is the exact expected output?

Comment: Thank you for comment. I need the mean in this case. I edited the example as well.

Comment: What do you want the results to be if a group does not meet your missingness requirements? Drop it? Keep it, but list the aggregation as `NA`? Keep it unaggregated?

Comment: I would like to have NA in return if the condition is not beeing met

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would convert to long format, make the calculations, and then convert back to wide. (I bumped the threshold up to 0.27 so there would be more results using the sample data.)

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

dat %>% 
  pivot_longer(-group) %>%
  group_by(group, name) %>%
  mutate(prop_missing = mean(is.na(value))) %>%
  group_by(group) %>%
  mutate(include = all(prop_missing < .27)) %>%
  group_by(group, name) %>%
  summarize(result = case_when(first(include) ~ mean(value, na.rm = TRUE), TRUE ~ NA_real_)) %>%
  pivot_wider(id_cols = group, names_from = name, values_from = result) 
# # A tibble: 4 x 4
# # Groups:   group [4]
#   group     x     y     z
#   <fct> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
# 1 a      12.1  11.6  11.9
# 2 b      12.1  11.6  11.8
# 3 c      NA    NA    NA  
# 4 d      NA    NA    NA
```

Answer (score 1):

One option:

```
cols2check <- c("x", "y", "z")
out <- colMeans(dat[cols2check], na.rm = TRUE)
out[sapply(dat[cols2check], function(x) mean(is.na(x)) < 0.2)] <- NA_real_
out

#        x        y        z 
# 12.11241 11.59669       NA
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a way to get what you want using `data.table`:

```
library(data.table)
dt <- as.data.table(dat)
> dt[, 
+    lapply(.SD, function(z){
+        return(ifelse(test = mean(is.na(z)) > 0.2, 
+                      yes = NA_real_, 
+                      no = mean(z, na.rm = T))) 
+    }), 
+    by = .(group)]

# Output
   group        x        y        z
1:     b       NA 12.22819 12.23798
2:     c       NA 12.15508       NA
3:     d 12.35357 12.20275 12.22628
4:     a 12.32877       NA       NA
```

If you only want rows where no column value is `NA`, you can wrap the call in `na.omit` which should return row 3 in this example:

```
> na.omit(dt[, 
+            lapply(.SD, function(z){
+                return(ifelse(test = sum(is.na(z))/length(z) > 0.2, 
+                              yes = NA_real_, 
+                              no = mean(z, na.rm = T))) 
+            }), 
+            by = .(group)])
   group        x        y        z
1:     d 12.35357 12.20275 12.22628
```